# gsoap response memory allocation nested structure

Tags: memory, nested, structure, allocation, gsoap

Im trying to find the right way of allocation memory for the following structure.

```
struct part1 {
      char* c1;
      char* c2;
}
struct part2 {
    int a;
    struct part1 *local;
}

struct response {
      struct part1* p1;
      struct part2* p2;
}
```

This is what I do, as gathered from the documents.

int myservice ( soap *soap, struct request *request, struct response *resp) {
...
   // top level resp is setup by soap_serve

```
resp->p1 = soap_new_ns__part1(soap,1);
resp->p1->c1 = soap_new_string(soap,10); (also tried soap_malloc(soap,10))
resp->p1->c2 = soap_new_string(soap,10);
strcpy(resp->p1->c1, “first”)
strcpy(resp->p1->c2, “second”)

resp->p2 = soap_new_ns__part2(soap,1);
resp->p2->a = 123;
resp->p2->local = soap_new_ns__part1(soap,1);
resp->p2->  c1 and c1 as above
etc...
```

But this seems to end in memory leak; although I call the soap_destroy, soap_end.
I am using the process_queue example for the server implementation.

Is there an obvious problem that I am not seeing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working to modify the gsoap libraries, or are you simply using the generated soap code in your application?  And from your examples, I am assuming you are using `C`, not `C++`, is that correct?

Comment: By the way, if/when you reply to this, be sure to tag my username in the comment to get my attention.  (i.e. use _@ryyker_)

Comment: Hi @ryyker . Thanks for the response. I am not editing gsoap. simply using the libraries. and no intention to modify them either. and yes I am using the C version.

Comment: Well, this is all pretty old by now, you have hopefully solved you problem by now!, In case you ever need it though ( regarding _seems to end in memory leak..._  ) there is an example of what I have done to accommodate these nested structs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837772/645128)